# PHP and Javascript compatible encryption functions

Tags: php, javascript, function, encryption

I would like to know if there is a Javascript counterpart to the PHP oppenssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt functions.

I have developed a unique combination of PHP and AJAX where a user can log in to a website using their username and password and be authenticated without the username or password even being transmitted to the server.  The point is, both the server and the user have a never-transmitted secret key that can be used as an encryption key.

*I mention this because many of the "answers" I have found here are arguments about why anyone needs to do this, because "any secret key that you use will have to be transmitted".  Not the case here, so please don't comment if you are a naysayer.*

What I am really looking for is two sets of string encryption/decryption functions that are compatible between PHP and Javascript, using a secret key.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I don't know about `openssl_...` things, but you can download a js to encrypt / decrypt things with `blowfish` algorithm. Blowfish is in php too (mcrypt contains this algorithm by defualt).

I googled and found a link

http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/

You can always google things, you may find the same for openssl too!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first comment on [`openssl_decrypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) for the PHP bit, and then you can get the [Gibberish Javascript bit here](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php).